# Hadoop - File to block mapping

Tags: hadoop

When the JobTracker assigns a map task to a TaskTracker, does it need to talk to NameNode? Or it can get the information from the InputSplit itself? 
When I look at the code, I see that the  InputSplits are packed with BlockLocations. Would the JobTracker go with this information or does it need to work with Namenode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client calculates the split informations and writes them with the split info to HDFS.

You can have a look into Hadoop 1.x `JobSplit.SplitMetaInfo` there is the serialization implemented that also serializes the locations.

The jobtracker just picks up these serializations and schedules them, where the locations are just a hint for faster execution if slots are available.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. So, this is just a hint? Lets take the scenario. Lets say the JobTracker identifies the data to be run is sitting on the local drive of the TaskTracker, would it inform this to the TaskTracker? Or the TaskTracker would get in touch with the NameNode to identify this?

Comment: There is no such communication. The scheduler inside of the Jobtracker will look into the `SplitMetaInfo` and if there is a slot available on that location it will send a directive to the tasktracker to run a task with that input.

Comment: If the data is not available in the machine (no DataLocal), whose responsibility it is to find the machine where the data resides? Does the TaskTracker needs to talk to NameNode or can it still make use of the metadata (containing block locations) and directly talk to the other machine?

Comment: OK, just went thru the SplitMetaInfo and see that the locaction info is packed along with other data. The confusion is because I'm reading a book which talks about "MapReduce tasks" talking to NameNode while reading a file. Would this scenario ever occur?

Comment: You are confusing the daemons with each other. The Jobtracker only schedules on the information from the splits. A MapReduce TASK (a mapper or a reducer) is always talking to a namenode, because it needs to write data out of the task and read the data, in case of a datanode not responding, it looks for other replicated data sources by querying the namenode.

Answer (score 0):

The JobTracker does contact the NameNode to get the block locations. This process can especially take a while if the number of blocks the job is dealing with is extremely large.

Comment: Thanks Donald. My confusion is related to why the Job Tracker has to do this as the InputSplit does have metadata about the possible locations and hosts from which it can get the data from. Thanks.

Comment: The InputSplit doesn't actually know. It needs to go to the NameNode to find out.